# Как скрыть Layout? Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QLayout`, нужно его скрыть. У виджетов есть метод `hide()`, у `layout'ов` нет. Не хочу скрывать все виджеты в лейауте.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В качестве размышления ... лайаут виджета - это не визуальный элемент, это способ размещения дочерних элементов. А нам нужно дочерние элементы скрыть ...

Вариант 1. Скрываем сам элемент, содержащий требуемый лайаут

Вариант 2. "Бегаем" по дереву дочерних элементов, и "скрываем" их

Я бы взялся за дизайн по варианту 1.